# Warning: Attempt to present UIModalItemsPresentingViewController on UIModalItemAppViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am frequently getting this warning

```
"Warning: Attempt to present `<_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController:>  on 
<_UIModalItemAppViewController:> which is already presenting 
<_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController:>"`
```

error in iOS 7, and after that my application hang ...

I am using Xcode5 and iOS 7.0.4.

Comment: Same problem here. Happens on calling presentViewController()

Comment: In my case this error appears because I am trying to launch the Game Center Login screen while also trying to display an Alert letting them know how many bullets they have earned (while sleeping). I am trying to dismiss first before displaying the View Controller:  [rootVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; //now present the Game Center Login screen [rootVC presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil]; It still happens once in awhile, so this isn't the correct solution.